# how to show vectorTile on non-geographical maps

Tags: leaflet, gis, vector-tiles

I have displayed the grid tile layer on the map using Leaflet L.TitleLayer. Now, I have a geojson file and want to display on the map .

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "id":1,
         "properties":{
            "Entity":"LWPolyline",
            "Handle":"5D11",
            "Layer":"JMD",
            "LyrFrzn":0,
            "LyrLock":0,
            "LyrOn":1,
            "LyrVPFrzn":0,
            "LyrHandle":"16D",
            "Color":6,
            "EntColor":-1,
            "LyrColor":6,
            "BlkColor":0,
            "Linetype":"Continuous",
            "EntLinetyp":"Continuous",
            "LyrLnType":"Continuous",
            "BlkLinetyp":null,
            "Elevation":0.000000,
            "Thickness":0.000000,
            "LineWt":0,
            "EntLineWt":0,
            "LyrLineWt":0,
            "BlkLineWt":-1,
            "RefName":null,
            "LTScale":1.000000,
            "ExtX":0.000000,
            "ExtY":0.000000,
            "ExtZ":1.000000,
            "DocName":"03.dxf",
            "DocPath":"F:\\dataChange\\03.dxf",
            "DocType":"DXF",
            "DocVer":"AC1021",
            "height":0.000000,
            "Shape_Leng":18.192087
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  3121034.4810791016,
                  534863.26330566406
               ],
               [
                  3121039.9448852539,
                  534866.55871582031
               ],
               [
                  3121041.3472900391,
                  534864.23352050781
               ],
               [
                  3121035.8834838867,
                  534860.93811035156
               ],
               [
                  3121034.4810791016,
                  534863.26330566406
               ]
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

What map should I choose to complete it? Because the geojson is too big(the code above is just a part of it), I need to use vectorTile .  Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. You should add your attempt at solving the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

My recomendations:

1) put your data into PostGIS database;

2) use PostGIS ST_ASMVT, ST_ASMVTGEOM functions to get vector tile data (pbf binaries) from your backend (nodejs/asp.net/php etc.);

3) to get vector tiles you can use mapnik (nodejs bindings) or mapserver (fastcgi, mascript is unable to produce mvt output). Mapnik and mapserver are able to consume geojson source directly (without postgis app layer).

4) use openlayers (my choice) or Leaflet or MapBox GL js client to display vector tiles in the browser. I prefer OL because it is more customizable and can display vector tiles in different projections (not only in web mercator).
Using mapserver or mapnik allows to produce images and use other output formats (pdf, kml etc) in addition to MVT's (if you need it) and many other cool features like labeling, querying, geotransformations etc. Using MVT's requires client-side styling but image tiles are rendered completely on server. But PostGIS way is lightweight, fast and pretty easy.

There are lot of other ways to produce vector tiles. For example, gdal ogr implementation (https://www.gdal.org/drv_mvt.html) supports layers.